# SKPSMTPMessage emails

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I am using SKPSMTPMessage to send emails to a list of emails. since the user selects the amount of emals from his contacts, he could choose 1 as well as 200. I wanted to know, if I use this lbrary to send emails, when the user closes the app, or simply keeps it running in the background, does the app keep sending the emails, just like the Email Apple app?

Comment: No.  It will certainly finish the last couple messages before it is killed by the system, but the thread it's in will not stay alive very long without a background task declaration.

Comment: So if there are 100emails to be sent, and the user closes the app at 10emails senot, the system will send some more (e.g. 20) and then stip unless there is a background task decleration? If so how can I do a background task decleration?